# Why there is difference in actual flashlight of phone and in react native torch package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have developed one flashlight app. In that, I noticed when I turn on flashlight from our default flashlight option in the phone, it appears white and bright, whereas when I turn it on from my app it is little yellowish and dull.
I have used a `react-native-torch` package to develop my app, I noticed this difference in MI device.
I have followed the steps as shown on [react-native-torch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torch).

Answer (score 2):

As said [here](https://github.com/ludo/react-native-torch/issues/23), the brightness of the flashlight when using the react-native-toch module it's not the maximum.

For IOS, there's [this](https://github.com/joseph-perez/react-native-torch) fork of the project who made changes to select the level of the brightness.

There's too [this](https://github.com/ConnectedHomes/react-native-torch) fork wich is 20 commits ahead of the original repository, so you can fork it and search where's the brightness level configuration.

Comment: thank you for yout response ill check it and update here